# React Native Expo AV source with authorization

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm trying to load a .mp4 video in a managed RN app from a REST API. It should be an authorized request. I did the same with images with RN  and had no issues. I'm testing on Android emulator.

I tried this:

```
<Video
  style={{ width: "80%", height: "80%" }}
  ref={videoRef}
  source={{
    uri,
    headers: {
      Authorization: token
    }
  }}
 useNativeControls
 resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
 onError={(error) => console.log(error)}
/>
```

I tried with loadAsync as well:

```
<Video
   style={{ width: "80%", height: "80%" }}
   ref={videoRef}
   useNativeControls
   resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
   onError={(error) => console.log(error)}
/>
<Pressable
   onPress={() => videoRef.current.loadAsync({
        uri,
        headers: { Authorization: token },
   })}>
   LOAD
</Pressable>
```

and with androidImplementation in loadAsync:

```
onPress={() => videoRef.current.loadAsync({
   uri,
   headers: { Authorization: token },
   initialStatus: { androidImplementation: 'MediaPlayer' }
})}
```

The error I have - 'ia.w0: None of the available extractors (c, d, b, g, k, b, a0, d, h0, e, h, b, e, f, b, a) could read the stream.'